# Issue while converting IFormFile to string

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, mapping, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working a asp.netcore 3.1 project. I have 2 table with one to many relationship.

I am facing an issue in converting VideoId form IFormFile to String.

Here is my model and viewModel.

ParentModel.cs

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string VideoId { get; set; }    // inside ParentModel videoId is string type
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

ParentViewModel.cs

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IFormFile VideoId { get; set; } // inside ParentViewModel VideoId is IFormFile type
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

ParentController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] ParentViewModel parent)
{
    var result = await _ParentService.Create(_mapper.Map<ParentModel>(parent)); // this line is ok. After this line VideoId is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile
    
    if (parent.Child.Count > 0)
    {
        int id = 0;
        
        foreach (var child in parent.Child){
            var videoIdString = await _helper.UploadImage(child.VideoId, "path");    // In this line I convert videoId of child of ParentViewModel to string from IFormFile. Now VideoId is path.mp4
        }
        id++;
    }
    // I have to update VideoId of child of ParentModel with that coverted videoIdString
    
    
    await _ParentService.Update(result);
    return Created(nameof(Get), result);
}
```

I have to update `VideoId of the child of ParentModel` with converted `videoIdString`

How Can I do this? Anyone ideas, please...

Comment: your form must have enctype="multipart/form-data" to send data to the controller check that file come from form or not

Comment: No that's not my probelm, my problem is how to map result.Child.VideoId 
 and parent.Child.VideoId

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need this `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`
because the default is on trying to understand from my code

```
public class MParent
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<child> Children { get; set; }
    }
    public class Mchild
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string VideoId { get; set; }   
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

and view model

```
 public class Parent
    {
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<child> Children { get; set; }
    }
    public class child
    {
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IFormFile VideoId { get; set; } 
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

and my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(child child, IFormFile myfile)
    {

        Mchild mychild = new Mchild()
        {
            ParentId = child.ParentId,
            VideoId = myfile.FileName
        };
        myfile.CopyToAsync(myfileLoctionTosaveVideo);
        _context.add(mychild);
        _context.savechanges();

        return View();
     }
```

and you can do these with file
[image]